# Symfony2 knp menu - main menu builder from current bundle

Tags: symfony

Now, in twig base template I have something like this:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AdminBundle:Builder:mainMenu') }}
```

But I want to have something like:

```
 {{ knp_menu_render('current-bundle:Builder:mainMenu') }}
```

And I want to have in each bundle different `Builder:mainMenu`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I do this

```
{% set menu = app.request.get('_template').get('bundle')~':Builder:mainMenu'  %}
{{ knp_menu_render(menu) }}
```

and all working :)